# Did I do anything bad by attempting to mount a Drobo volume?

Tags: drobo

While looking around the Drobo control panel for my [B800i](http://www.drobo.com/storage-products/b800i/), I clicked on the little "X" in the Mount column by one of the volumes by accident.

[image]
<sup>I pulled this image off the Internet and it is not my setup.</sup>

Drobo thinks it isn't formatted (it actually has a lot of important data on it, but it's managed by Xen, and apparently Drobo doesn't know about that file system). Therefore, it asked me to create a file system and suggested NTFS. I hit Cancel in that dialog, since I didn't want to do that. Even so, after the dialog went away, the little X became a spinning icon. Nothing seemed to happen, so I closed the Drobo Dashboard application after a brief moment.

Later, I noticed some slowness while working with a Drobo volume from a Windows VM on the Xen server, but that might be normal/unrelated. Did I do something terrible to my Drobo volume? What does the spinning icon in the Mount column mean?

Comment: Eww, Drobo.  Which specific model, and do you have access to the underlying device/OS, without having to suffer the use of their control panel?

Comment: @HopelessN00b It's a [B800i](http://www.drobo.com/storage-products/b800i/), I think. I'm not sure what you mean by "underlying device" - I can connect with iSCSI.

Comment: Not knowing if it was one of their model SAN, or some one of their Linux-based NASes, I was wondering if you had like a CLI interface or whatever else, or if you had to use the Drobo control panel.